# Regex to get a word between slashes

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with regex.
I'm not sure how to figure one regex for several cases.

I have a lines with text like:

```
/REPORTMONTH/April
/CONTRACT/2/156/0001/285
//DATE/24032013
```

I need to get the first word after slash `/` or two slashes `//` at the beginning:

i.e. `REPORTMONTH`, `CONTRACT`, `DATE`. This should be the first item.

The second item is to get everything after a word with `/`:

i.e. `April`, `2/156/0001/285`, `24032013`

As you see the word `2/156/0001/285` has slashes as well. So, it should be taken into consideration.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is `nsregularexpression` tag used? Are you developing for Apple iOS? Either `C#` or `nsregularexpression` must be removed.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Oops, added by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uss this regex:

```
^/+([^/]+)/(.*)$
```

And grab the text in captured groups #1 and #2.

- [.NET RegEx Demo](https://www.myregextester.com/?r=258ef5bc)
- [RegEx Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dM4vG8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example:

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"^//?(?<first>[^/]+)/(?<rest>.*)$",
    RegexOptions.Multiline);

//`${first}` will contain the first element, and
//`${rest}` will contain the remaining part of the line.
```

Comment: I think the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option is redundant, I removed it just now.